# Parsing JSON into a Map

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse following JSON string into key-value pairs, so that I can insert it into a table in database.

```
{
    "name": "MyMobile",
    "category": "cellphone",
    "details": {
        "displayAspectRatio": "97:3",
        "audioConnector": "none",
        "motherBoard": {
            "Rom": "256GB",
            "Ram": "8GB",
            "Battery": "400mAH"
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to parse the JSON string using the following code with `GSON` and store it into a `Map`. But unfortunately, it's not working well for nested JSON objects.

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> createHashMapFromJsonString(String json) {

JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(json);
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = object.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = set.iterator();
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = iterator.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    JsonElement value = entry.getValue();

    if (null != value) {
        if (!value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            if (value.isJsonObject()) {

                map.put(key, createHashMapFromJsonString(value.toString()));
            } else if (value.isJsonArray() && value.toString().contains(":")) {

                List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                JsonArray array = value.getAsJsonArray();
                if (null != array) {
                    for (JsonElement element : array) {
                        list.add(createHashMapFromJsonString(element.toString()));
                    }
                    map.put(key, list);
                }
            } else if (value.isJsonArray() && !value.toString().contains(":")) {
                map.put(key, value.getAsJsonArray());
            }
        } else {
            map.put(key, value.getAsString());
           }
       }
   }
   return map;
  }
}
```

I would expect the below rows in my Map. Can anyone please guide me with the correct approach?

```
name = MyMobile
category = cellphone
details.displayAspectRatio = 97:3
details.audioConnector = none
details.motherBoard.Rom = 256GB
details.motherBoard.Ram = 8GB
details.motherBoard.Battery = 400mAH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nested JSON the above problem could be solved by Recursion. See below code. Note: Only Handles Map, //TODO ArrayList & Exception Handling

```
@Test
public void testJsonToMap() {
    String data = "{\"name\":\"MyMobile\",\"category\":\"cellphone\",\"details\":{\"displayAspectRatio\":\"97:3\",\"audioConnector\":\"none\",\"motherBoard\":{\"Rom\":\"256GB\",\"Ram\":\"8GB\",\"Battery\":\"400mAH\"}}}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map jsonMap = gson.fromJson(data, Map.class);
    System.out.println(jsonMap);

    Sep2019JavaTest test = new Sep2019JavaTest();
    Map opMap = test.toMap(jsonMap, new HashMap<String, Object>(), "");
    System.out.println(opMap);
}

private Map toMap(Map ipMap, Map opMap, String parentKey) {
    if (ipMap != null && !ipMap.isEmpty()) {
        ipMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
            String key = parentKey.isEmpty() ? k.toString() : parentKey.concat(".").concat(k.toString());
            if (v.getClass() == LinkedTreeMap.class) {
                toMap((Map) v, opMap, key);
            } else {
                opMap.put(key, v);
            }

        });
    }
    return opMap;
}

//Output
//{details.motherBoard.Rom=256GB, details.motherBoard.Battery=400mAH, name=MyMobile, category=cellphone, details.audioConnector=none, details.motherBoard.Ram=8GB, details.displayAspectRatio=97:3}
```